# Buttons have no text on Android 4.0.4 device

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-button

I've been developing an app on Android 5.1.1, and everything works fine.  But when I test it on a 4.0.4 device, none of the buttons display any text.  Any idea why this would be?

Each button is the UI of a fragment.  This is the layout, named `just_a_button.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/button_copper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

This is an example of how the fragments set up their views:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Button button = (Button) inflater.inflate(R.layout.just_a_button, container, false);
    button.setText(R.string.member_info);
    // set click listener omitted
    return button;
}
```

The button's visibility is controlled by an event receiver.  The button is shown as expected, and its click listener works.  There's just no text on it.

**Edit:** The solution was to put the button inside a layout.  I'm still curious if this requirement was ever documented, and why only the text seems to be affected when the button is the root view.

Comment: why is the button text color white??

Comment: @Clairvoyant Because the `@style` I'm using is dark.

Comment: when do you change the visibility from gone to visible?

Comment: @YonatanNir After another fragment completes a HTTP request.  It broadcasts an object parsed from the response on an event bus, and each button fragment receives it and sets its own visibility.  The buttons themselves are visible, just not the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this

```
button.setText(R.string.member_info);
```

use

```
button.setText(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.member_info));
```

You are directly defining string resource, but `setText()` takes `string` as parameter.

**Edit:**
change you xml like below and then findviewbyid for your button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/Mybutton"
    style="@style/button_copper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

In your fragment `onCreateView()` do as below :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.just_a_button, container, false);
    Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Mybutton);
    button.setText(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.member_info));
    // set click listener omitted
    return view;
}
```

Comment: No difference.  There's a version of `setText()` that takes the resource ID.

Comment: The layout you are using for button, does the button tag is parent tag?? can you show the layout code for your fragment

Comment: Updated my answer check it out

Comment: Putting the button inside a `RelativeLayout` solved the problem.  I guess the fragment's view has to be some kind of `ViewGroup`.  I'm still using the version of `setText()` that takes a resource ID.